# How to make ImageMagic identify accept input from a pipe?

Tags: linux, imagemagick, pipe, zsh, identify

Trying to pipe list of images from **find** to **identify** and I get no output.

Using this command, I get no results.

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f | identify -format '%w:%h:%i'
```

However, if I use this command, which doesn't use a pipe but instead uses **find**'s ***`-exec`*** option it works normally.

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f -exec identify -format '%w:%h:%i\n' '{}' \;
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to use pipe properly instead of `find -exec`?

Comment: `find -iname '*.jpg' -type f -exec identify -format '%w:%h:%i\n' {} +`. This will run `identify` on large batches of files instead of fork+exec for each of them. Or use `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 identify ...`.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, I needed to use **xargs**

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f | xargs -I '{}' identify -format '%w:%h:%i\n' {}
```

the brackets **'{}'** are used to represent the file array.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
identify -format '%w:%h:%i\n' $(find . -iname "*.jpg")
```

Note: I have added \n so that each image will list on a new line.

Comment: Interesting approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your first command, namely this:

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f | identify -format '%w:%h:%i'
```

doesn't work because `identify` expects the filenames as parameters, not on its `stdin`.

---

If you want to make `identify` read filenames from a file, you would use:

```
identify -format '%w:%h:%i\n' @filenames.txt
```

---

If you want to make `identify` read filenames from `stdin`, (this is your use case) use:

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f | identify -format '%w:%h:%i\n' @-
```

---

If you want to get lots of files done fast and in parallel, use **GNU Parallel**:

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -print0 | parallel -0 magick identify -format '%w:%h:%i\n' {}
```

Comment: Mark, Good point about @-. Note: some systems may need their policy.xml ImageMagick file edited to permit use of that.